# Incomplete type when using a protected member array in C++

Tags: c++

I have a simple C++ app. When I try to use `sizeof` with a member variable I get an error that `"Incomplete type is not allowed"`.  When I make the variable global (like define it outside of `main`) I do not get this error.

Why is this?

In code my issue looks like this:

```
class example : public application
{
private:
    void init()
    {
        // The "sizeof" call raises an error, "incomplete type is not allowed"
        glNamedBufferStorage(vbo, sizeof(vertices), vertices, 0);
    }

   const GLfloat vertices[] = {1, 2, 3};
}
```

And if I define `const GLfloat vertices[] = {1, 2, 3};` outside of the class (make it global) this works.

```
const GLfloat vertices[] = {1, 2, 3};
class example : public application
{
private:
    void init()
    {
        // This works
        glNamedBufferStorage(vbo, sizeof(vertices), vertices, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Apart from anything else, protected data is A Bad Idea.

Comment: What happens if you define ``example::init`` outside of the class instead of inline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the size of `vertices` when you declare it.  You can't use an initializer to specify the size for an empty array in a class (Language spec section dcl.init.aggr, paragraph 5).

```
const GLfloat vertices[3] = {1, 2, 3};
```